# Find the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $\frac{n}{d}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could anyone help me to prove this basic result in elementary number theory?

> Let $n,d$ be two natural numbers with $n\geq 2 $ and $d \mid n $, prove that
>
> $$ \gcd(n,\frac{n}{d}) = \frac{n}{d}$$

It seems vary basic but I am really stuck!

I know many basic theorems of number theory that might be helpful (like Bézout's lemma), but I have no idea how to proceed with the proof.

Through a contradiction? maybe a straight proof?

We used this in class, with out any further explanation, in order to prove a theorem in group theory, and I really need to understand that step.

Thank you.

Comment: First show that $\frac{n}{d}$ is a divisor of $n$ and a divisor of $\frac{n}{d}$. Next show that it is the _greatest_ common divisor of $n$ and $\frac{n}{d}$ (there's really nothing to show here - nothing greater than $\frac{n}{d}$ can divide $\frac{n}{d}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, go back to definitions.

n/d divides n/d and it divides n.  (d*n/d = n).  So n/d is a common divisor.  If x > n/d then x is not a divisor of n/d (divisors have to be smaller) so n/d is the greatest common divisor.

---

In light of marty cohen's answer.  Note: gcd(m, a*m) = m always as m|m and m|a*m so m|gcd(m, a*m) and gcd(m,a*m)|m so m|gcd and gcd|m $\implies$ m = gcd(m, a*m).

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{n}{d}$ is just a number c that c|n. And obviously that gcd(n,c)=c for every c|n

Answer (score 1):

If
$m = gcd(n, n/d)$
then
(1) $n/d\ |\ m$
since $n/d$ divides both
$n$ and $n/d$;
(2) $m\ |\ n/d$
since
$gcd(a, b)$ divides
both $a$ and $b$.

Therefore
$m = n/d$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $d\mid n $ then $n=d.m$ with m integer and then $m\mid n$. Finally, $gdc(n,m)=m$